# Refresh token automatically via Postman

Tags: api, postman, token

When testing some api, the token need to be generated each 3min and I would like to do the refresh automatically, I did the following

I have a collection "CollectionGetter" which contain some requests

- from "CollectionGetter" collection :

1. I've added the following script in "Tests" tab

> var jsonData = pm.response.json();
> pm.environment.set('getToken', jsonData.access_token);

2. on authorozation tab,set :
   Type = Bearer token
   Token {{getToken}}

then selected a request under CollectionGetter :
getAccount  (GET url/api/account)
Auth = inherit autho from parent
and sent it
=> got a  401  JSONError: No data, empty input at 1:1

Any help ?
is my configuration correct

Comment: I have an idea: write a script in `Pre-Request` of collection 1. read the `exp` value of token (from environment) to check whether this token expires or not. 2. if `exp` < `now`, use `pm.sendRequest` to get new token. 3. save new token.

Comment: this is what I did, but didn't work. I added it in Test and not in prequest...

Comment: Why did you add it in Test? token is needed before calling the request, not after. And to help it works for all request in collection, best place would be `Pre-Request of Collection`

Answer (score 0):

**Postman now has a feature that auto refresh auth tokens**, you just need to setup authentication at the collection level and togle "the auto refresh access token" option:
[Image showing the auto refresh access token button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vLj3.png)

here's **postman walktrough video** about that feature, worth a watch:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAhs9TBK-xU

TLDW:

> 1 - Click on your collection, it'll open the "auth" tab.
>
> 2 - Configure you Authentication type with Oauth 2.0
>
> 3 - Scroll to the bottom of the page and set your credentials and
> click "get new access token"
>
> 4 - Go up and togle the "Auto-refresh access token" option:
> [Auto-refresh access token option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8hOD.png)
>
> 5 - With your token already generated go to your request, open the
> authorization tab of the request and set "type" to "inherit auth from
> parent", everything should work just fine.

Aditional resource: [postman blog post about the feature](https://blog.postman.com/oauth-2-0-token-refresh-and-id-token-support/)

Comment: I followed this exact steps but "Auto-refresh token" is still disabled. Any idea?

Comment: @BakulG probably because the refresh token is not present. There is an open ticket to tackle this scenario: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11887